# Load external JSON file in PaperJS

Tags: javascript, json, paperjs

I thought this would be really simple to do with:

`project.importJSON('structures.json')`

Unfortunately this gives me:

`JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "structures"`

This `"structures"` must come from the JSON file `structures.json` itself which looks like this:

```json
{
    "structures": [
        {"name":"shed",     "width": 4, "height": 3,    "depth": 5},
        {"name": "house",   "width": 6, "height": 7,    "depth": 5},
        {"name": "factory", "width": 4, "height": 3.5,  "depth": 6.5, 
                                                        "depth_sub_1": 5.5, 
                                                        "depth_sub_2": 4.5 }
    ]   
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? I'd rather not use jQuery for this.

**Edit**

So it seems to me that using importJSON can only work when the JSON is an actual Paper object. The same error keeps on occurring.

What's the alternative? I want **my external 'structural' data** in what is *basically* a JavaScript file. Should I use the regular route for doing so?

My html looks something like this:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/javascript/paper-full.js"></script>
  <script type="text/paperscript" src="I/a_view_on_my_structures.js" canvas="phase-I"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="phase-I" resize="true"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stringify your data.

```
var structures = {
    "structures": [
        {"name":"shed",     "width": 4, "height": 3,    "depth": 5},
        {"name": "house",   "width": 6, "height": 7,    "depth": 5},
        {"name": "factory", "width": 4, "height": 3.5,  "depth": 6.5, 
                                                        "depth_sub_1": 5.5, 
                                                        "depth_sub_2": 4.5 }
    ]   
}
project.importJSON(JSON.stringify(structures))
```

if you json data is in a different file you should read that file first

This is how you read a file

**synchronously**

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', 'path/to/your/file', false);
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //your data is in client.responseText
    console.log(client.responseText);
  }
  client.send(null);
```

**asynchronously**

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', 'path/to/your/file');
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //your data is in client.responseText
    console.log(client.responseText);
  }
  client.send();
```

notice that when you do this, you don't need to stringify your data, because you read it as a text, so you just have to pass the `client.responseText` content to the `importJSON` function

Comment: Yes, how to do this? It's in the same folder, what's the elegant solution?

Comment: @Code-MonKy I explained better in my edit, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me a lot.